# How do I handle DatabaseIOException File System Error (12)

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

When I launch my Blackberry application a web service call is made. When the web service response comes back I then store that data into an SQLite database.

I'm fairly certain that only one connection can be made to the SQLite File at any one time, but this poses a problem for me.

My app runs in the background when the user exits. If he launches (which calls the web service and database method), exits and then launches again I get the error:

```
DatabaseIOException File System Error (12)
```

Now I can guess that this is happening because both web service calls are trying to interact with the same database file. In fact all of the interactions in my app are with this one database file.

I guess one of my questions would be:

If two connections to the database file are created one after the other and an error is thrown, do both connections just die or does the first connection finish what it was doing??

Also, what's the best way to handle this type of scenario. What checks should be performed before opening another connection??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Two thing can be here one that your system did not awake properly and before that your database code is executing. So its obvious you will got this exception and the second thing may be you are not closing the database properly. You can use `finally block` to close your Database.

Comment: Thanks. The database is closing fine, but because the data I'm retrieving is quite large at times I think it's more of a timing issue. I think what is happening is I'm trying to open a connection to that database when it is still busy processing something else. If this exception is thrown, what happens to the connections?? Are they both killed or is the first one carried out and the second killed?